# Can't get Jquery to write the output of a function to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

new guy here. I have a feeling this is an extremely basic question but I can't get this Jquery code to write the output of the function to html and have it show up. I believe it's an issue with the script but unsure if I am doing something wrong with html as well.

The goal of this function is to create a calculator that gives future investment value based on what the user inputs. When I click submit, It used to change all of the html to show just 'NaN' but now when I click the submit button, it clears the input boxes but does not give me any number or any answer even though I believe I've set it to display the number to

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id = "futurevalue">
        <form>
            <input type="radio" name="formula" value="future_investment" checked>Future Investment<br>
            <label for="princeple">Enter the princeple amount invested:</label>
            <input id="princeple" type="number" name="princeple" step="0.01"><br>
            <label for="time">Enter how long the investment will be for (in years):</label>
            <input id='time' type='number' name='time'><br>
            <label for='rate'>Enter the expected interest rate:</label>
            <input id='rate' type="number" name='rate'><br>
            <input id='submit' type='submit' name='submit'>
        </form>
        <p>Total:</p>
        <p id='result'></p>
    </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $('#submit').click(function(){
    $('#result').html(function(){
        return toString(output,10);
    });
});
var princeple = parseInt($('#princeple'),10);  
var time = parseInt($('#time'),10);
var rate = parseInt($('#rate'),10);
var output = (princeple * time + rate);
```

Comment: Use [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your fix:

```js
$('#submit').click(function(){
  var princeple = parseInt($('#princeple').val());  
  var time = parseInt($('#time').val());
  var rate = parseFloat($('#rate').val()/100);
  var output = ((princeple * rate) * time);
  $('#result').html(output);
  //prevent from page reload
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "futurevalue">
        <form>
            <input type="radio" name="formula" value="future_investment" checked>Future Investment<br>
            <label for="princeple">Enter the princeple amount invested:</label>
            <input id="princeple" type="number" name="princeple" step="0.01"><br>
            <label for="time">Enter how long the investment will be for (in years):</label>
            <input id='time' type='number' name='time'><br>
            <label for='rate'>Enter the expected interest rate:</label>
            <input id='rate' type="number" name='rate'><br>
            <input id='submit' type='submit' name='submit'>
        </form>
        <p>Total:</p>
        <p id='result'></p>
    </div>
```

You have to calculate the value inside the `click` event and assign to the `result`. The formula for calculating interest is also incorrect.

Comment: this works in the Code snippet on Stack Overflow, but for some reason when I try it in my documents in the live preview it will not work. It still comes up with nothing. I even copy and pasted, letter for letter. The only thing I added to the jQuery code was $(document).ready(function(){}); and enclosed all the code you gave me within the {} of function.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle or plunkr and check

Comment: I did, result was odd. I see that you've added the /100 and changed up the output slightly. but Once I return those back to normal, I am still receiving weird values.

Comment: /100 is for rate as rate is in percent and to calculate interest you need to multiply all three parameters.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But I was just first doing a very simplistic equation to make sure that I was able to get the output to show up. The equation is the easy part, the getting jQuery to print to html was the hard part for me.

Comment: But my answer also corrects the equation so it should be accepted isn;t it?

Comment: It does appear to work now? The code seems to be very hit or miss, or I am doing something wrong (still very new) but I like to have the entire formula laid out in area as well. Thanks! I guess I have two options for answers now. My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code, basically you need:
Calculate your variables inside cb click and than output the resut in your div `#result`. Use `.val` to get values for your inputs and `event.preventDefault()` to avoid form submit (which is the browser default behavior).

```js
$('#submit').click(function(event) {
  var princeple = parseInt($('#princeple').val(), 10);
  var time = parseInt($('#time').val(), 10);
  var rate = parseInt($('#rate').val(), 10);
  var output = (princeple * time + rate);
  $('#result').html(output);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="futurevalue">
  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="formula" value="future_investment" checked>Future Investment<br>
    <label for="princeple">Enter the princeple amount invested:</label>
    <input id="princeple" type="number" name="princeple" step="0.01"><br>
    <label for="time">Enter how long the investment will be for (in years):</label>
    <input id='time' type='number' name='time'><br>
    <label for='rate'>Enter the expected interest rate:</label>
    <input id='rate' type="number" name='rate'><br>
    <input id='submit' type='submit' name='submit'>
  </form>
  <p>Total:</p>
  <p id='result'></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! Now it's time to figure out how to let it calculate decimals in the final output without it rounding down.

Comment: @AKA In my code I calculate variables inside the click callback and than output the result in div #result. In your original question you calculate your variable outside the onclick. I hope it helps :)